# How are achieved PUFs (Physicaly Unclonable Functions) and can we workaround?

Tags: obfuscation, hardware

I would like to know how are achieved PUFs (Physicaly Unclonable Functions) and if there is a way reverse these hardware electronic components ?

Recent papers such as "[Invasive PUF Analysis](http://nedos.net/fdtc2013.pdf)" present techniques to extract information from PUFs but, I would like to better understand the basic principles of PUFs and what are the problems when trying to clone it.

Comment: Check [Dmitry Nedospasov](http://nedos.net/)'s website and presentations.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly this kind of input I was looking for (and I still want somebody to explain me how PUF is working! :)). Thanks Ange !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking to better understand the basic principles of PUFs, I would warmly recommend the [lecture notes of Boris Skoric](http://security1.win.tue.nl/~bskoric/physsec/files/LectureNotes_2IC35_v1.4.pdf). Chapter 5 is all about PUFs: history, examples, applications and entropy. Some of the things presented there are also formalized, which requires a decent level of information theory knowledge.